# Apply neuralnet training function on Date Type in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a dataset as follows-

```
Transaction.Date    Transaction
26/05/2014  Dr.
26/05/2014  Dr.
22/05/2014  Cr.
21/05/2014  Dr.
17/05/2014  Dr.
12/5/2014   Dr.
6/5/2014    Dr.
3/5/2014    Dr.
3/5/2014    Dr.
1/5/2014    Cr.
29/04/2014  Cr.
26/04/2014  Dr.
25/04/2014  Dr.
19/04/2014  Dr.
10/4/2014   Cr.
31/03/2014  Dr.
31/03/2014  Cr.
```

I want to run neuralnet prediction on the above set of data but I have one as Date type and other as numeric and while running

*I have converted Transaction Dr.(0) and Cr.(1)*

```
output <- neuralnet(Transaction ~ Transaction.Date,trainset,hidden = 5,threshold = 0.1)
```

naturally its throwing error as Date is not numeric type-

```
Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
```

One way I figured out is I separated each date field ie Day-MONTH-YEAR as a separate column and then I ran the formula-

```
Transaction ~ date.day+date.month+date.year
```

Is there any other better way I can derive from the data above to run in neural network in R?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the best approach?

Comment: I didn't mention as Best approach .. I just found a way to do that ... and I wanted to know some better way of doing this

Comment: I know it's probably a little late now, but have you considered using fuzzy logic for months or season as inputs for the date and month, and perhaps age for years?  For example, June the 1st of this year could be 0.5 Summer, 0.5 Spring, 0.0 Winter, 0.0 Fall and 0 Years old (depending of hemisphere of course!).